# Edit multiple files using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to edit multiple files using awk in the following way:

```
awk '{F = FILENAME ".inp"; print $0 > F ; if(NR==3) print  "%moinp usr/speciale/br/brhgooh/scan/newscan/freqBZ/cas/prov2/",FILENAME  > F }' *.xyz
```

It works well with the first file, but in the rest of the files the change does not appear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `NR` is a running count of the number of records read from all files; `FNR` is a running count of the number of records read from each file; you can see this with `awk '{print FNR,NR}' *.xyz` ... notice how the first column (`FNR`) resets to `1` each time a new file is opened; try changing `NR` to `FNR`;

Comment: Don't create all upper case variable names like `F` to avoid clashing with awks builtin variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `FNR` not `NR`

- `NR` is the record number of *all records seen thus far*
- `FNR` is the record number of *the current file*

Adding some whitespace helps readability:

```bash
awk '
    BEGINFILE {
        close(F)
        F = FILENAME ".inp"
    }
    {print > F}
    FNR == 3 {print "%moinp usr/speciale/br/brhgooh/scan/newscan/freqBZ/cas/prov2/" FILENAME  > F }
' *.xyz
```

If your awk does not have `BEGINFILE`, you can use `FNR == 1` instead.

Other changes:

- `print` instead of `print $0` ($0 is the default)
- `print "%mo .../" FILENAME` *without* a comma -- a comma will insert a space after the slash.
- `close(F)` to prevent "too many open files" errors